# Minimum subdomain length

Tags: http, dns

I've googled this a few different ways but I haven't been able to find anything official.

**What is the minimum subdomain length?**

From what I understand, a domain has to be at least 3 characters, but I haven't been able to find anything about the minimum for a subdomain.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[RFC 1034 section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-3.1) specifies that labels (parts of DNS names) can be from 0 to 63 octets long, and the zero-length one is reserved for the root zone only. So in practice, the limits are 1 to 63 characters.

Answer (score 4):

Considering the fact that I've seen plenty of sites with just "m" as a subdomain (for mobile versions of pages), I would guess that the minimum length is 1.

Answer (score 0):

DNS works happily with 1-character (sub)domains.

*Second-level* domains (those you buy from a registrar) are another deal. Since there are so few short strings, you'll surely have to talk at length with a registrar to register a 2-character domain, or even a 3-character domain, or, more likely, to pay a hefty sum to its current owner.